# What's a simple way to output homebrewed synthesized sound on Unix?

Tags: c, unix, audio, sound-synthesis

I want to do some sound synthesis on Mac OS X (and ideally other Unix-like OS) using ANSI C.

This is for learning purposes rather than "I need a solution, any solution, quick!"

Say I have an 8-bit buffer in my C program that I update 22050 times a second. How can I get my speakers to output that as a waveform?

Comment: not exactly what you asked, but maybe it can help you, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379353/what-is-a-lightweight-cross-platform-wav-playing-library/

Comment: @quinmars libao does looks excellent and lightweight. Please put it as an answer so that you can get some rep points.

Comment: done, but I haven't found any reference that libao supports OSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no POSIX audio API or something similar. So if you want sound support on Linux, OSX, etc. you need a library that wraps around the native sound APIs of the different OSs. Take a look on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379353/what-is-a-lightweight-cross-platform-wav-playing-library/). It's not asking directly for OSX, but most of the answers should also work for it, except maybe libao. At least I haven't found anything on their homepage, that says they support OSX.

Comment: libao-0.8.8\src\plugins\macosx :-)

Comment: Accepted this one because it's a little simpler. Anyone else on OS X, if you can't get the driver to initialise with a manually compiled version, install it using `MacPorts`

Answer (score 3):

SDL can play sound buffers. But PortAudio may work better PA will call your C callback when it needs more data, and then you can hand it the next buffer. It's fairly easy actually.

Comment: +1 for portaudio. A simple sound output can be written in less than 20 line.. Open an Output-Stream and write to it.. Done!