# Cross platform WAVE Audio playback in C++

Tags: c++, audio, cross-platform

I have written an application which converts an integer into its spoken English equivalent.
This code passes filenames to be played by the `PlaySoundA` function in the Windows API:

```
vector<string> sounds = NumberConvert(atol(argv[1]));

    int i;
    for (i=0; i < sounds.size() - 1; i++) {
        sounds[i].append(".wav");
        PlaySoundA(sounds[i].c_str(), 0, SND_SYNC);
    }
```

Would it be possible to create a wrapper function which would use the PortAudio API in the background, to maintain cross platform compatibility?

Comment: [What is a lightweight cross platform WAV playing library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379353/what-is-a-lightweight-cross-platform-wav-playing-library)

Comment: I apologise if this question is not concise enough.

Comment: question contains the answer for playing wav file with portaudio. Portaudio itself is cross platform.check link on comnent again

Comment: @Edition, are you saying you want a wrapper that replaces PlaySoundA with a call to something in PortAudio on systems that don't have PlaySoundA.

Comment: @Jasen yes, something like a wrapper function

Comment: http://www.portaudio.com/faq.html#WAV  does not look promising, but this guy got it working. https://github.com/albertz/music-player-core/blob/master/examples/portaudio-wavplay-demo.cpp
I have has success with `sdlaudio` in the past. http://www.gamedev.net/topic/581517-simplest-way-to-play-a-sound-in-sdl-c/